# Difficulty installing MySQLdb on Lion - import cannot find module

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm having difficulty getting MySQLdb working for:

- OSX 10.7.3
- Python 2.7.1 (64-bit)
- MySQL 5.1.62-osx10.6-x86_64

  - Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.62, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1 (is that conflicting? I had a 32-bit version before installing 64)
- MySQLdb 1.2.3
- Setuptools installed

I need MySQL 5.1 for compliance with the site I'm working with.

When I "import mysqldb" in python, I get "No module named mysqldb."

Thanks for helping me out! Let me know what I should try.

---

The python path includes

```
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg'
```

And the sudo python setup.py install has

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
Copying MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
MySQL-python 1.2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `import MySQLdb`; imports are case-sensitive and this module has silly case.

Comment: An embarrassing, useful lesson. Thanks very much for the prompt answer!